# Can i legally remove a credit from a free plugin on wordpress.org?

Tags: plugins, licensing, accessibility

I am using this accessibility plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/accessible-poetry/

I didn't like to logo in the bottom of it that adds a link to the plugin site so I removed it via css.

But I couldn't find anywhere any clarification on this, how the plugin is licensed, and can I just remove the logo without worrying of getting in trouble if I do it in my client's site?

Comment: downvoted and closes voted as this is a legal related question you should ask lawyers not developers. In any case, any change you will do, regardless if legal or not, will most likely be overwritten with the next plugin update. If ypu do not like the way the plugin work, just don't use it.

Comment: @Mark Kaplun You wrote completely unrelated stuff, this question is directed to developers since wordpress is an open source CMS which developers built and not lawyers. it is relevant to ask other developers about the terms of use of other's code. If you would spent a bit of time trying to read my question you would understand I do like how the plugin works I just think it needs some modification, which isn't overwritten with the next plugin update because I'm not editing directly the plugin file (I assume you are a trashy lawyer and not a developer  :) ).

Comment: just because something is open source do not mean you can do everything with it. Just because someone claims his plugin is GPL do not mean it is GPL (maybe he just copied someone else work and have no right to change the license). When you have a legal question as you specified in the title, the people you should ask should be  lawyers not developers.

Comment: @MarkKaplun You are clearly not connected to earth, I asked where to check the licensing, not what a GPL license is! that is not a question for a lawyer, if I went for my lawyer and asked him hey do you know where can I see the license for a wordpress plugin that was uploaded to wordpress.org, what do you think he will answer? clearly he will have no clue. And I don't expect him to. and for the part you said about copying work, when I download a plugin from the wordpress repository, I assume it's legitimate. If not, the fault is on the plugin author not me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin is licensed under the [GPL (GNU General Public License)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License), so you can modify it as you please. You can even redistribute your modified version, as long as you do so under the GPL and adhere to its requirements.

That said, even if it wasn't, I believe you would be allowed to add CSS, since you are not even modifying the plugin in any way. I personally would look for a way to actually remove that link from the output, though, not just via CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, does all the free plugins licensed under GPL license, or this is a specific case, could you please guide me where to find license information on the plugin page?

Comment: I believe all plugins (and themes) that are published via wordpress.org have to be licensed as GPL. You can make sure that the authors did understand that by looking at the source (on the plugin page on wp.org, go to the Development-tab, click "Read more" and then "Browse the code", enter "trunk" and look at the readme.txt or main php file, in this case accessible-poetry.php, and you'll see in "License: GPL2" in the comment at the top).

Comment: In order to store a plugin on wordpress.com, the licence must be GPL compatible (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#the-guidelines) then these rules are the same for all plugins that you found in the backoffice in "Plugins" -> "Add New"